# Why don't asset catalogs enforce me using the right size images?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I originally saw the new asset catalog feature in XCode5 and was pretty pleased - no more messing about with dozens of different versions of the files, I thought.

But it doesn't seem to actually make anything any easier. It still doesn't simply tell me "you need an image of 114x114 pixels here". And it seemingly will let me specify *any* image of *any* size for each icon variant. Does it magically resize my images, or will things just break, if I supply a 50x50 icon when it expects a 72x72 one?

All I want is a list of "these are the exact files you need to supply" and "these are the ones you didn't supply yet". Perhaps I am misunderstanding how this is to be used, because a utility which won't complain about being given bad data seems worse to me than no utility at all!

Comment: I was playing around with this last night, when I tried to run the application with the incorrect sizes it spat out a whole bunch of errors, didn't you get any errors?

Comment: Waiting until I run the app is dumb though - and do you have to try running on every simulator combination to make sure they're all correct?

Comment: Yeah I fully agree with that, it should almost prevent you from adding images if they are the incorrect size. Which I think it used to do before asset catalogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is, as you said: a list of "these are the exact files you need to supply" and "these are the ones you didn't supply yet", maybe you can try the the "Don't use asset catalogues" option of the drop-down menu of App Icons or Launch Images.

Here it is what it will look like then:

[image: App Icons menu]